# http-proxy-middleware not proxying requests if placed after cookieparser

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

> 1. The middleware works properly if placed before the cookie parser.But
>      the session becomes undefined.
> 2. If i move the proxy middleware after the cookie parser it does not
>      proxy requests silently fails without any errors.I tried creating a post request but nothing happens.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cors = require('cors');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var config = require('config');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    client:redisClient
  }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use(cors());

//proxy middleware
app.use('/api', proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:4000', 
    changeOrigin: true, 
    onProxyReq:  function (proxyReq, req, res) {
      proxyReq.setHeader('USER_ID', req.session.user_id);
      proxyReq.setHeader('TOKEN',config.get('token'));
    }      
}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

> http-proxy-middleware npm module middleware

```
app.use('/api', proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:4000', 
    changeOrigin: true, 
    onProxyReq:  function (proxyReq, req, res) {
      proxyReq.setHeader('USER_ID', req.session.user_id);
      proxyReq.setHeader('TOKEN',config.get('token'));
    }      
}));
```

Comment: `cookie-parser` isn't required anymore for recent versions of `express-session` (and may even cause issues, as is mentioned [in the manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionoptions)). Also, between `cookieParser` and your API handler there are other middleware being declared, are you sure it's not related to those?

Comment: which middleware you talking `middleware `?

Comment: @Ritchie updated the question.talking about the http-proxy-middleware npm module middleware.

Comment: @robertklep: cookieparser was the problem removing it fixed the problem.thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping any parser middlewares, It will format your request, which is not expected by `http-proxy-middleware`.
We should place proxy middleware before parser middleware or you can try it out.

```
onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
    if (req.body) {
      const body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
      proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      proxyReq.setHeader('content-length', body.length)
      delete req.body
      proxyReq.write(body)
      proxyReq.end()
    }
  },
```

Note: Changes has to be done with respect to content type